# How can we retrieve the data in the Sitecore HTML Cache?

Tags: caching

We are creating a report page where we will display the cached data source / presentation . A button will be there to remove selected cached item.

Which Sitecore Api can we use to retrieve the list of cached items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching on Sitecore API's i got `Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager` class which has method `GetHtmlCache` and it returns `Sitecore.Caching.HtmlCache`.
With the below code I can retrieve the list of cache items.

```
            List<Sitecore.Caching.Cache.CacheEntry> cacheList = new List<Sitecore.Caching.Cache.CacheEntry>();
       Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext siteContext = Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.GetSite("SiteName");

            if (siteContext != null)
            {
               Sitecore.Caching.HtmlCache htmlCahe = Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetHtmlCache(siteContext);
                var cacheKeys = htmlCahe.InnerCache.GetCacheKeys();

                foreach (var sKey in cacheKeys)
                {
                    Sitecore.Caching.Cache.CacheEntry entry = htmlCahe.InnerCache.GetEntry(sKey, false);

                    cacheList.Add(entry);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good introductory articles about Sitecore caching, e.g. [this one](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/Developers/Articles/2009/07/CachingOverview.aspx).

Generally you should use `CacheManager` to work with cache:

```
HtmlCache cache = Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.GetHtmlCache(Sitecore.Context.Site);
cache.Remove(cacheKey);
```

Other methods related to removing items from cache are `RemovePrefix()` and `RemoveKeysContaining()`.

Comment: Nice article, it has good information on caching.